# Problem when trying to execute a file

Tags: executable

I am trying to execute or run a file in Ubuntu, by using `./filename` on the command line.  When I try and run it, I get this error:

```
Error: A mode argument is required
```

There is no file extension on the file. The file is called `oracle` and as far as I know, there shouldn't be a problem with the file.

How do I fix the error and run the file?

Answer (score 2):

The file your are trying to start requires AT LEAST 1 ARGUMENT.

[As you can see here](http://grokbase.com/p/gg/golang-checkins/139sapp41e/go-tools-push-by-adono-google-com-go-tools-oracle-change-mode-argument-into-subcommand-on-2013-09-25-18-34-gmt) the method used here is `oracle callgraph <package>` and the code in the software has your message:

```
args := flag.Args()
+ if len(args) == 0 || args[0] == "" {
+ fmt.Fprint(os.Stderr, "Error: a mode argument is required.\n"+useHelp)
+ os.Exit(2)
```

It will exit the program with that error message if the amount of arguments is zero or is it is empty.

---

If your filename is `filename` I expect it needs to be at least

```
oracle filename
```